# Assign value to variable using procedure

Tags: c, function, procedure

so i want to calculate angle and area of a triangle, but i need to assign the value of input and output using procedure. i cant find any examples about this and already tried some variation, but still have problem with using the pointer.

what i got so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define pi 3.141592654

// Declaration
void input(void);//get user input for triangle's sides
void calculate(int* x,int* y,int* z);//calculating area and angle

//main program
int main(void){

int x,y,z;
double a,b,c,height;

input(x,y,z);
calculate(x,y,z);
printf("angle a : %.3f degree\n",a);
printf("angle b : %.3f degree\n",b);
printf("angle c : %.3f degree\n",c);
printf("Area : %.3f cm2\n",height);


return 0;
}

//Definition
void input(int* x, int* y, int* z)
{
    printf("insert side x :\n");
    scanf("%d",*&x);
    printf("insert side y :\n");
    scanf("%d",*&y);
    printf("insert side z :\n");
    scanf("%d",*&z);
}
void calculate(int* x,int* y,int* z)
{
    int s
    s=(*x + *y + *z)*0.5;
    *Area=sqrt(s*(s-x)*(s-y)*(s-z));
    *a=acos(((*x * *x)+(*z * *z)-(*y * *y))/2(*x)(*z));
    *b=acos(((*y * *y)+(*z * *z)-(*x * *x))/2(*y)(*z));
    *c=acos(((*x * *x)+(*y * *y)-(*z * *z))/2(*x)(*y));
}
```

i got error in scan user input for x,y,z and assign degree and area result to area,a,b,c

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: im sorry then, but my main topic is assigning variables in main program using procedure and function. that addition because error "your post mostly program"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create needed arguments in both declaration and definition.
- I don't think using pointers where they are not needed is good.

Your code should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define pi 3.141592654

// Declaration
void input(int* x,int* y,int* z);
void calculate(double* a, double* b, double* c, double* Area, int x,int y,int z);

//main program
int main(void){

    int x,y,z;
    double a,b,c,height; /* It maybe good to rename height to Area */

    input(&x,&y,&z);
    calculate(&a,&b,&c,&height,x,y,z);
    printf("angle a : %.3f degree\n",a);
    printf("angle b : %.3f degree\n",b);
    printf("angle c : %.3f degree\n",c);
    printf("Area : %.3f cm2\n",height);

    return 0;
}

//Definition
void input(int* x, int* y, int* z)
{
    printf("insert side x :\n");
    scanf("%d",x);
    printf("insert side y :\n");
    scanf("%d",y);
    printf("insert side z :\n");
    scanf("%d",z);
}
void calculate(double* a, double* b, double* c, double* Area, int x,int y,int z)
{
    double s; /* type of s should be double, not int in this case */
    s=(x + y + z)*0.5;
    *Area=sqrt(s*(s-x)*(s-y)*(s-z));
    *a=acos(((x * x)+(z * z)-(y * y))/(2 * x * z));
    *b=acos(((y * y)+(z * z)-(x * x))/(2 * y * z));
    *c=acos(((x * x)+(y * y)-(z * z))/(2 * x * y));
}
```

Comment: thank you but, it seems the degree calculation was wrong, i tried the program with 3 4 5 sides, and add     180 / pi * acos ............... (convert radian to degree)and  result should be 36 53 90 but showing 90 90 90 instead. im sure nothing wrong with that equation http://www.calculator.net/triangle-calculator.html. why ?

Comment: You did the division in `calculate()` in integer, so the values are truncated. Change three `2` used in `calculate()` to `2.0`.